# Directly Obtaining the $n$th Value of a Lucas Sequence

Tags: recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

(As an aside: This question lies relatively upon the border between the realms of Computer Science and Mathematics, and thus may be appropriate for StackOverflow as well.)

I am in need of a method of computationally finding the $n$th number of a Lucas Sequence of the first kind.

Given integer parameters $P$ and $Q$, a Lucas Sequence of the first kind $U_n(P, Q)$is defined by the following recurrence relation:

$U_0(P, Q) = 0$

$U_1(P, Q) = 1$

$U_n(P, Q) = P \cdot U_{n-1}(P, Q) - Q \cdot U_{n-2}(P, Q)$ for $n > 1$

This naturally lends itself to a recursive process, however for large values of $n$, this tends to be particularly time intensive, and cannot be performed by a computer in any reasonable amount of time.

I managed to implement the process iteratively, which massively reduced the time required to calculate the $n$th value, but for large numbers, the process is still quite time consuming.  This is due to the fact that both recursive and iterative algorithms require computing every value $U_0(P, Q), U_1(P, Q), ... ,U_{n-1}(P, Q)$ in order to obtain a value for $U_n(P, Q)$.  This leads me to my question:

Is there a way of computing the $n$th number of a Lucas Sequence of the first kind (given parameters $P$ and $Q$) directly, without calculating each prior value in the sequence?  A direct equation, if such a thing exists, could be computed in relatively trivial time.

Comment: Let $V_n$ be the corresponding Lucas sequence of second type.
we have

$$\begin{align}
U_{n+m} &= \frac12\left(U_nV_m + U_mV_n\right)\\
V_{n+m} &= \frac12\left(V_nV_m + \Delta U_n U_m\right)
\end{align}\quad\text{ where }\quad\Delta = P^2 - 4Q.$$

To compute $L_N$, break $N$ into a sum of powers $2^k$, compute $L_{2^k}$ appear in the expansion and then combine the result. It takes $O(\log_2 N)$ steps using only integer arithmetic.

Comment: The method that achille hui describes can be thought of as a slight generalization of binary exponentiation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), but for a certain $2 \times 2$ matrix rather than a number. You shouldn't expect to do any better than this because the $N^{th}$ term generally has a number of digits linear in $N$ anyway, so it takes $O(\log N)$ time even to print the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way of computing the $n$th number of a Lucas Sequence of
>   the first kind (given parameters $P$ and $Q$) directly, without
>   calculating each prior value in the sequence?

[Yes (assuming $P^2 \ne 4Q$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence#Distinct_roots), but it's unlikely to give any computational advantage:

$$U_n(P,Q) = \frac{a^n - b^n}{a - b}$$
where
$$a = \frac{P+\sqrt{P^2 - 4Q}}{2}\\
b = \frac{P-\sqrt{P^2 - 4Q}}{2}.$$

([Koval's algorithm](http://www.scirp.org/journal/PaperInformation.aspx?PaperID=3368#.VThsiyFViko) might be the fastest available.)

Comment: Excellent, thank you.

Comment: Update: I implemented the linked algorithm and it is extremely fast. Fantastic source. Thank you.